# Is Embedded software a good way to do embedded hardware?

Tags: embedded, hardware, firmware

What are the advantages and disadvantages of using an embedded software to do embedded hardware?

Comment: Did you re-read your question? It makes no sense to me.

Comment: We didn't get your question. Hardware is always important, without no hardware there is no software. Please add some more information.!

Comment: Some of the hardwares on the board can be replaced with embedded software. For example, FPGA board manufacturers provides Microblaze processor as a soft/firm IP core which can be programmed using Xilinx ISE instead of providing it as dedicated hardware in order to save some sapce.

Comment: If that is your real question, can't you come up with any answers yourself? This smells of homework...

Comment: Vote to reopen.  The question was certainly clear to me -- did anyone read either of the answers?

Answer (score 1):

In some cases you can replace hardware with firmware. For example you might implement a counter or an LCD or LED controller or an SPI controller with firmware using general purpose I/O pins.

The disadvantages usually relate to speed- a circuit made with hardware can respond in nanoseconds, and can be relatively jitter-free. Firware implementations can have large jitter and slow response, depending on exactly how they are implemented (polled or with interrupts, for example). They also may take a bit more development effort than just slapping down a dedicated piece of hardware.

The advantage may be cost reduction (and board space and maybe power as well).

Answer (score 1):

Firmware can be used to emulate hardware peripherals when either the microcontroller doesn't have the type of peripheral you need, or you need multiple of the same type and that many are not available (e.g. you need two UART's and the microcontroller only has one.

Some of the peripherals that can be emulated are:

- SPI, I²C, UART and other serial protocols.  This is generally
  referred to as "[bit-banging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_banging)".
- ADC [using a digital pin](http://letsmakerobots.com/content/low-cost-adc-using-only-digital-io)
- DAC [using multiple digital pins](http://idle-spark.blogspot.com/2015/04/an-8-bit-static-dac-using-only-4.html)
- Comparator -- can make one out of two ADC inputs (see above)
- PWM [using a digital pin](http://nicks-liquid-soapbox.blogspot.com/2011/02/pwm-on-any-digital-pin-on-arduino.html)
- DSP -- emulation of MAC instruction, circular buffers, bit reversed addressing etc.

The one thing all of these have in common is very accurate timing.  This can require a very fast processor.

For example, if one wants to "bit-bang" a UART interface at 115,200 baud (the highest baud rate in common use), a bit is going to have a width of 8.69 µs.  In order to accurately find the middle of the start bit, one should scan at least 8 times faster, or 1 µs.  (Hardware UARTs typically scan twice that fast, or 16X.)  A *hardware* input capture module would really help here.  But you'd still need to scan the middle of the startr bit µs later.

The main advantage to emulating hardware with firmware, is it makes up for the lack of a particular peripheral on a microcontroller, or more often, makes up for an insufficient number of a particular type of peripheral.

It also saves having to add extra peripherals to the PCB such as UART's, ADC's, DAC's etc. on a SPI or I²C to make up for the lack of a peripheral on the microcontroller.

The main disadvantage is the amount of programming time required, and the need for extra timers.  Code space is probably not to much as issue, except for the DSP.